# Sum of each row and column in 2D array (C)

Tags: c, arrays

I want to get the sum of each row and column of an array and print them one by one in C. I done half of work but I can't progress any more. There it is my code:

```
int n,m;
void sum_row_column(int array[n][m],int r,int c,int i,int j)
{
int sum_of_column1=0;
int sum_of_row1;

for(j=0,i=0;i<r;i++)
{
    sum_of_column1=sum_of_column1+array[i][j];
    if(i==r-1)
    {
        printf("\nSum of %d.column: %d\n",j+1,sum_of_column1);
        j=j+1;
    }
}

for(i=0,j=0;j<r;j++)
{
    sum_of_row1=sum_of_row1+array[i][j];
    if(j=c-1)
    {
        printf("\nSum of %d.row: %d\n",j+1,sum_of_row1);
        i=i+1;
    }
}
```

As you can see it prints just first row's sum and column's sum. I thought if I add

```
i=0;
```

after

```
printf("\nSum of %d.column: %d\n",j+1,sum_of_column1);
j=j+1
```

line, it can move second column and sum it too. But when I add

```
i=0;
```

the program go into infinite loop without any errors.
This code is in the header but don't worry in the rest of the code there aren't any mistake.

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant.

Comment: What is the point of taking `i` and `j` as parameters in a function when you immediately change their value to `0`?

Comment: I know it is quite weird. But if not i=0 after j=j+1 how can I progress in second column's sum in this loop. Otherwise I have to write a for loop for every column's sum but its impossible because I dont know how many colums or rows in array.

Answer (score 3):

#### Suggested code for the task

You have:

```
int n,m;
void sum_row_column(int array[n][m],int r,int c,int i,int j)
{
```

Although this compiles, it is poorly-defined code, and is unnecessarily subject to failure if the global variables `n` and `m` are not set correctly.  There is no need for that level of coupling, and if you do use that level of coupling, the variables `r` and `c` are superfluous. You should be using:

```
void print_sum_rows_cols(int r, int c, int array[r][c])
{
```

This allows the code to be used to print any shape of matrix using VLA (variable length array) notations.  The variables `n` and `m` should be unnecessary; the parameters `i` and `j` seem to be pointless too since you ignore the values passed to the function, setting both to `0` at the start of the loops.

Summing the columns is simple:

```
for (int col = 0; col < c; col++)
{
     int colsum = 0;
     for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
         colsum += array[row][col];
     printf("Sum for col %d = %d\n", col, colsum);
}
```

Summing the rows is equally straight-forward:

```
for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
{
     int rowsum = 0;
     for (int col = 0; col < c; col++)
         rowsum += array[row][col];
     printf("Sum for row %d = %d\n", row, rowsum);
}
```

Assembling an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void print_sum_rows_cols(int r, int c, int array[r][c])
{
    for (int col = 0; col < c; col++)
    {
        int colsum = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
            colsum += array[row][col];
        printf("Sum for col %d = %d\n", col, colsum);
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
    {
        int rowsum = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < c; col++)
            rowsum += array[row][col];
        printf("Sum for row %d = %d\n", row, rowsum);
    }
}

static void dump_matrix(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols])
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d):\n", tag, rows, cols);
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            printf("%3d", matrix[r][c]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int a1[3][4] =
    {
        { 68, 78, 50, 46, },
        { 64, 12, 47,  1, },
        { 86, 10, 84, 62, },
    };
    int a2[5][3] =
    {
        {  4, 30, 19, },
        { 79, 58, 20, },
        { 95, 12, 24, },
        { 20, 37, 72, },
        { 17,  0, 53, },
    };

    dump_matrix("A1", 3, 4, a1);
    print_sum_rows_cols(3, 4, a1);

    dump_matrix("A2", 5, 3, a2);
    print_sum_rows_cols(5, 3, a2);

    return 0;
}
```

The code in the (renamed) `print_sum_rows_cols()` function maintains the question's variable names, though they aren't the names I'd use in my own code.  (For those, see the "Analysis of another answer" section.)

And the output:

```
A1 (3x4):
 68 78 50 46
 64 12 47  1
 86 10 84 62
Sum for col 0 = 218
Sum for col 1 = 100
Sum for col 2 = 181
Sum for col 3 = 109
Sum for row 0 = 242
Sum for row 1 = 124
Sum for row 2 = 242
A2 (5x3):
  4 30 19
 79 58 20
 95 12 24
 20 37 72
 17  0 53
Sum for col 0 = 215
Sum for col 1 = 137
Sum for col 2 = 188
Sum for row 0 = 53
Sum for row 1 = 157
Sum for row 2 = 131
Sum for row 3 = 129
Sum for row 4 = 70
```

Note that this prints the inputs so that the outputs can be checked manually against the inputs.  This is a useful technique in debugging.

## Deconstructing an alternative answer

In an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47728976/15168) (revision 1), [Jozeph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9058618/jozeph) has shown code which, it is claimed, works.  When indented in an orthodox format, the code is:

> ```
> int n;
> int m;
>
> void sum_row_column(int array[n][m], int r, int c, int i, int j)
> {
>     int sumOfColumn = 0;
>     int sumOfRow = 0;
>     printf("\n");
>     for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
>     {
>         sumOfRow = 0;
>         for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
>         {
>             sumOfRow += array[i][j];
>         }
>         printf("Sum of %d.row=%d\n", i + 1, sumOfRow);
>     }
>     printf("\n");
>     for (j = 0; j < r; j++)
>     {
>         sumOfColumn = 0;
>         for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
>         {
>             sumOfColumn += array[i][j];
>         }
>         printf("Sum of %d.column=%d\n", j + 1, sumOfColumn);
>     }
> }
> ```

There are multiple problems with this code, some already identified but repeated in a marginally different form here:

- The size of the matrix is identified by the values in the file scope (global) variables `n` and `m`.
- The size of the matrix is also identified by the parameters `r` and `c`.
- The values in the parameters `i` and `j` are unused; they're just a peculiar way of defining two local loop variables.
- Assuming it is possible to `assert(n == r && m == c);`, the first pair of nested loops (which sum the rows) is OK.
- Assuming it is possible to `assert(n == r && m == c && n == m):` (square matrix), the second pair of nested loop (which sum the columns) is OK, but it is mostly by accident rather than design.
- However, if the global variables are not in sync with the parameters, then the calculations in the first pair of nested loops are incorrect because the loops use the size `r`x`c` but the function assumes the array has size `m`x`n`.
- Similarly, if the global variables are not in sync with the parameters, or if the matrix is not square, the calculations in the second pair of nested loops are incorrect.  It doesn't even produce one 'column sum' for each column.

Here is an adaptation of my original answer to include the proposed answer (shown above) with some debug (read-only) printing added.  It also includes a minor variant of my original proposed function — the variables are renamed to suit my prejudices (short names for loop variables, longer names for function parameters, etc), plus the debug printing code.  The code also prints row sums before column sums to match the proposed answer's sequence, and it identifies the rows starting at row 1, column 1 instead of row 0, column 0.

There's also a 'bogus' variant of my answer (`bogus_sum_rows_cols()`) that uses the `n` and `m` variables to size the array; it produces the wrong answers when `n` and `m` are not in synchrony with `r` and `c`.  There's also a 'bogus' variant of the proposed answer (`bogus_sum_row_column()`) which does at least sum columns correctly if the array size in `r` and `c` matches both `n` and `m`.

```
/* SO 47719-9719 - Abuse of VLA definitions (and notations) */
#include <stdio.h>

static int debug = 0;

// Original answer (renamed variables, reordered results, and print row/col + 1)
static void print_sum_rows_cols(int rows, int cols, int array[rows][cols])
{
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        int rowsum = 0;
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            if (debug)
                printf("   a[%d][%d] = %d", r, c, array[r][c]);
            rowsum += array[r][c];
        }
        if (debug)
            putchar('\n');
        printf("Sum for row %d = %d\n", r + 1, rowsum);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
    {
        int colsum = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            if (debug)
                printf("   a[%d][%d] = %d", r, c, array[r][c]);
            colsum += array[r][c];
        }
        if (debug)
            putchar('\n');
        printf("Sum for col %d = %d\n", c + 1, colsum);
    }
}

static int n;   // Rows
static int m;   // Columns

// Adapted print_sum_rows_cols with size from n, m
// Using n, m is unnecessary coupling (and can lead to erroneous results)
static void bogus_sum_rows_cols(int array[n][m], int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        int rowsum = 0;
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            if (debug)
                printf("   a[%d][%d] = %d", r, c, array[r][c]);
            rowsum += array[r][c];
        }
        if (debug)
            putchar('\n');
        printf("Sum for row %d = %d\n", r, rowsum);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
    {
        int colsum = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            if (debug)
                printf("   a[%d][%d] = %d", r, c, array[r][c]);
            colsum += array[r][c];
        }
        if (debug)
            putchar('\n');
        printf("Sum for col %d = %d\n", c, colsum);
    }
}

// Original answer from OP - bogus results (debug printing added).
// Using n, m is unnecessary coupling (and can lead to erroneous results)
// Using i, j as arguments is bogus; the values passed in are ignored
// The 'sum column' loops are completely bogus.  The outer loop should
// iterate over columns [0..c) and the inner loop over rows [0..r).
// See print_sum_rows_cols() for the correct (minimal) interface.
static void sum_row_column(int array[n][m], int r, int c, int i, int j)
{
    int sumOfColumn = 0;
    int sumOfRow = 0;
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        sumOfRow = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            if (debug)
                printf("   a[%d][%d] = %d", i, j, array[i][j]);
            sumOfRow += array[i][j];
        }
        if (debug)
            putchar('\n');
        printf("Sum of %d.row=%d\n", i + 1, sumOfRow);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < r; j++)
    {
        sumOfColumn = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
        {
            if (debug)
                printf("   a[%d][%d] = %d", i, j, array[i][j]);
            sumOfColumn += array[i][j];
        }
        if (debug)
            putchar('\n');
        printf("Sum of %d.column=%d\n", j + 1, sumOfColumn);
    }
}

// Semi-fixed answer from OP - bogus results (debug printing added).
// Using n, m is unnecessary coupling (and can lead to erroneous results)
// Using i, j as arguments is bogus; the values passed in are ignored
// The 'sum column' loops are completely bogus.  The outer loop should
// iterate over columns [0..c) and the inner loop over rows [0..r).
// See print_sum_rows_cols() for the correct (minimal) interface.
static void bogus_sum_row_column(int array[n][m], int r, int c, int i, int j)
{
    int sumOfColumn = 0;
    int sumOfRow = 0;
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        sumOfRow = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            if (debug)
                printf("   a[%d][%d] = %d", i, j, array[i][j]);
            sumOfRow += array[i][j];
        }
        if (debug)
            putchar('\n');
        printf("Sum of %d.row=%d\n", i + 1, sumOfRow);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)     // c, not r
    {
        sumOfColumn = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < r; i++) // r, not c
        {
            if (debug)
                printf("   a[%d][%d] = %d", i, j, array[i][j]);
            sumOfColumn += array[i][j];
        }
        if (debug)
            putchar('\n');
        printf("Sum of %d.column=%d\n", j + 1, sumOfColumn);
    }
}

static void dump_matrix(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols])
{
    printf("Matrix %s (%dx%d):\n", tag, rows, cols);
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            printf("%3d", matrix[r][c]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

static void test_sequence(int v_debug, int v_n, int v_m, const char *tag,
                          int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols])
{
    debug = v_debug;
    n = v_n;
    m = v_m;
    dump_matrix(tag, rows, cols, matrix);
    printf("\nprint_sum_rows_cols():\n");
    print_sum_rows_cols(rows, cols, matrix);
    printf("\nbogus_sum_rows_cols() - (n = %d, m = %d):\n", n, m);
    bogus_sum_rows_cols(matrix, rows, cols);
    printf("\nsum_row_column()(n = %d, m = %d):\n", n, m);
    sum_row_column(matrix, rows, cols, -1, -1);
    printf("\nbogus_sum_row_column()(n = %d, m = %d):\n", n, m);
    bogus_sum_row_column(matrix, rows, cols, -1, -1);
    putchar('\n');
}

static void test_matrix_summation(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols])
{
    test_sequence(1,    2,    2, tag, rows, cols, matrix);
    test_sequence(0, rows, cols, tag, rows, cols, matrix);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a1[3][4] =
    {
        { 68, 78, 50, 46, },
        { 64, 12, 47,  1, },
        { 86, 10, 84, 62, },
    };
    int a2[5][3] =
    {
        {  4, 30, 19, },
        { 79, 58, 20, },
        { 95, 12, 24, },
        { 20, 37, 72, },
        { 17,  0, 53, },
    };
    int a3[3][3] =
    {
        { 96, 84, 13, },
        { 63, 29, 80, },
        { 97, 98, 48, },
    };

    test_matrix_summation("A1", 3, 4, a1);
    test_matrix_summation("A2", 5, 3, a2);
    test_matrix_summation("A3", 3, 3, a3);

    return 0;
}
```

The output from the code shown is:

```
Matrix A1 (3x4):
 68 78 50 46
 64 12 47  1
 86 10 84 62

print_sum_rows_cols():
   a[0][0] = 68   a[0][1] = 78   a[0][2] = 50   a[0][3] = 46
Sum for row 1 = 242
   a[1][0] = 64   a[1][1] = 12   a[1][2] = 47   a[1][3] = 1
Sum for row 2 = 124
   a[2][0] = 86   a[2][1] = 10   a[2][2] = 84   a[2][3] = 62
Sum for row 3 = 242

   a[0][0] = 68   a[1][0] = 64   a[2][0] = 86
Sum for col 1 = 218
   a[0][1] = 78   a[1][1] = 12   a[2][1] = 10
Sum for col 2 = 100
   a[0][2] = 50   a[1][2] = 47   a[2][2] = 84
Sum for col 3 = 181
   a[0][3] = 46   a[1][3] = 1   a[2][3] = 62
Sum for col 4 = 109

bogus_sum_rows_cols() - (n = 2, m = 2):
   a[0][0] = 68   a[0][1] = 78   a[0][2] = 50   a[0][3] = 46
Sum for row 0 = 242
   a[1][0] = 50   a[1][1] = 46   a[1][2] = 64   a[1][3] = 12
Sum for row 1 = 172
   a[2][0] = 64   a[2][1] = 12   a[2][2] = 47   a[2][3] = 1
Sum for row 2 = 124

   a[0][0] = 68   a[1][0] = 50   a[2][0] = 64
Sum for col 0 = 182
   a[0][1] = 78   a[1][1] = 46   a[2][1] = 12
Sum for col 1 = 136
   a[0][2] = 50   a[1][2] = 64   a[2][2] = 47
Sum for col 2 = 161
   a[0][3] = 46   a[1][3] = 12   a[2][3] = 1
Sum for col 3 = 59

sum_row_column()(n = 2, m = 2):

   a[0][0] = 68   a[0][1] = 78   a[0][2] = 50   a[0][3] = 46
Sum of 1.row=242
   a[1][0] = 50   a[1][1] = 46   a[1][2] = 64   a[1][3] = 12
Sum of 2.row=172
   a[2][0] = 64   a[2][1] = 12   a[2][2] = 47   a[2][3] = 1
Sum of 3.row=124

   a[0][0] = 68   a[1][0] = 50   a[2][0] = 64   a[3][0] = 47
Sum of 1.column=229
   a[0][1] = 78   a[1][1] = 46   a[2][1] = 12   a[3][1] = 1
Sum of 2.column=137
   a[0][2] = 50   a[1][2] = 64   a[2][2] = 47   a[3][2] = 86
Sum of 3.column=247

bogus_sum_row_column()(n = 2, m = 2):

   a[0][0] = 68   a[0][1] = 78   a[0][2] = 50   a[0][3] = 46
Sum of 1.row=242
   a[1][0] = 50   a[1][1] = 46   a[1][2] = 64   a[1][3] = 12
Sum of 2.row=172
   a[2][0] = 64   a[2][1] = 12   a[2][2] = 47   a[2][3] = 1
Sum of 3.row=124

   a[0][0] = 68   a[1][0] = 50   a[2][0] = 64
Sum of 1.column=182
   a[0][1] = 78   a[1][1] = 46   a[2][1] = 12
Sum of 2.column=136
   a[0][2] = 50   a[1][2] = 64   a[2][2] = 47
Sum of 3.column=161
   a[0][3] = 46   a[1][3] = 12   a[2][3] = 1
Sum of 4.column=59

Matrix A1 (3x4):
 68 78 50 46
 64 12 47  1
 86 10 84 62

print_sum_rows_cols():
Sum for row 1 = 242
Sum for row 2 = 124
Sum for row 3 = 242

Sum for col 1 = 218
Sum for col 2 = 100
Sum for col 3 = 181
Sum for col 4 = 109

bogus_sum_rows_cols() - (n = 3, m = 4):
Sum for row 0 = 242
Sum for row 1 = 124
Sum for row 2 = 242

Sum for col 0 = 218
Sum for col 1 = 100
Sum for col 2 = 181
Sum for col 3 = 109

sum_row_column()(n = 3, m = 4):

Sum of 1.row=242
Sum of 2.row=124
Sum of 3.row=242

Sum of 1.column=222
Sum of 2.column=130
Sum of 3.column=200

bogus_sum_row_column()(n = 3, m = 4):

Sum of 1.row=242
Sum of 2.row=124
Sum of 3.row=242

Sum of 1.column=218
Sum of 2.column=100
Sum of 3.column=181
Sum of 4.column=109

Matrix A2 (5x3):
  4 30 19
 79 58 20
 95 12 24
 20 37 72
 17  0 53

print_sum_rows_cols():
   a[0][0] = 4   a[0][1] = 30   a[0][2] = 19
Sum for row 1 = 53
   a[1][0] = 79   a[1][1] = 58   a[1][2] = 20
Sum for row 2 = 157
   a[2][0] = 95   a[2][1] = 12   a[2][2] = 24
Sum for row 3 = 131
   a[3][0] = 20   a[3][1] = 37   a[3][2] = 72
Sum for row 4 = 129
   a[4][0] = 17   a[4][1] = 0   a[4][2] = 53
Sum for row 5 = 70

   a[0][0] = 4   a[1][0] = 79   a[2][0] = 95   a[3][0] = 20   a[4][0] = 17
Sum for col 1 = 215
   a[0][1] = 30   a[1][1] = 58   a[2][1] = 12   a[3][1] = 37   a[4][1] = 0
Sum for col 2 = 137
   a[0][2] = 19   a[1][2] = 20   a[2][2] = 24   a[3][2] = 72   a[4][2] = 53
Sum for col 3 = 188

bogus_sum_rows_cols() - (n = 2, m = 2):
   a[0][0] = 4   a[0][1] = 30   a[0][2] = 19
Sum for row 0 = 53
   a[1][0] = 19   a[1][1] = 79   a[1][2] = 58
Sum for row 1 = 156
   a[2][0] = 58   a[2][1] = 20   a[2][2] = 95
Sum for row 2 = 173
   a[3][0] = 95   a[3][1] = 12   a[3][2] = 24
Sum for row 3 = 131
   a[4][0] = 24   a[4][1] = 20   a[4][2] = 37
Sum for row 4 = 81

   a[0][0] = 4   a[1][0] = 19   a[2][0] = 58   a[3][0] = 95   a[4][0] = 24
Sum for col 0 = 200
   a[0][1] = 30   a[1][1] = 79   a[2][1] = 20   a[3][1] = 12   a[4][1] = 20
Sum for col 1 = 161
   a[0][2] = 19   a[1][2] = 58   a[2][2] = 95   a[3][2] = 24   a[4][2] = 37
Sum for col 2 = 233

sum_row_column()(n = 2, m = 2):

   a[0][0] = 4   a[0][1] = 30   a[0][2] = 19
Sum of 1.row=53
   a[1][0] = 19   a[1][1] = 79   a[1][2] = 58
Sum of 2.row=156
   a[2][0] = 58   a[2][1] = 20   a[2][2] = 95
Sum of 3.row=173
   a[3][0] = 95   a[3][1] = 12   a[3][2] = 24
Sum of 4.row=131
   a[4][0] = 24   a[4][1] = 20   a[4][2] = 37
Sum of 5.row=81

   a[0][0] = 4   a[1][0] = 19   a[2][0] = 58
Sum of 1.column=81
   a[0][1] = 30   a[1][1] = 79   a[2][1] = 20
Sum of 2.column=129
   a[0][2] = 19   a[1][2] = 58   a[2][2] = 95
Sum of 3.column=172
   a[0][3] = 79   a[1][3] = 20   a[2][3] = 12
Sum of 4.column=111
   a[0][4] = 58   a[1][4] = 95   a[2][4] = 24
Sum of 5.column=177

bogus_sum_row_column()(n = 2, m = 2):

   a[0][0] = 4   a[0][1] = 30   a[0][2] = 19
Sum of 1.row=53
   a[1][0] = 19   a[1][1] = 79   a[1][2] = 58
Sum of 2.row=156
   a[2][0] = 58   a[2][1] = 20   a[2][2] = 95
Sum of 3.row=173
   a[3][0] = 95   a[3][1] = 12   a[3][2] = 24
Sum of 4.row=131
   a[4][0] = 24   a[4][1] = 20   a[4][2] = 37
Sum of 5.row=81

   a[0][0] = 4   a[1][0] = 19   a[2][0] = 58   a[3][0] = 95   a[4][0] = 24
Sum of 1.column=200
   a[0][1] = 30   a[1][1] = 79   a[2][1] = 20   a[3][1] = 12   a[4][1] = 20
Sum of 2.column=161
   a[0][2] = 19   a[1][2] = 58   a[2][2] = 95   a[3][2] = 24   a[4][2] = 37
Sum of 3.column=233

Matrix A2 (5x3):
  4 30 19
 79 58 20
 95 12 24
 20 37 72
 17  0 53

print_sum_rows_cols():
Sum for row 1 = 53
Sum for row 2 = 157
Sum for row 3 = 131
Sum for row 4 = 129
Sum for row 5 = 70

Sum for col 1 = 215
Sum for col 2 = 137
Sum for col 3 = 188

bogus_sum_rows_cols() - (n = 5, m = 3):
Sum for row 0 = 53
Sum for row 1 = 157
Sum for row 2 = 131
Sum for row 3 = 129
Sum for row 4 = 70

Sum for col 0 = 215
Sum for col 1 = 137
Sum for col 2 = 188

sum_row_column()(n = 5, m = 3):

Sum of 1.row=53
Sum of 2.row=157
Sum of 3.row=131
Sum of 4.row=129
Sum of 5.row=70

Sum of 1.column=178
Sum of 2.column=100
Sum of 3.column=63
Sum of 4.column=194
Sum of 5.column=107

bogus_sum_row_column()(n = 5, m = 3):

Sum of 1.row=53
Sum of 2.row=157
Sum of 3.row=131
Sum of 4.row=129
Sum of 5.row=70

Sum of 1.column=215
Sum of 2.column=137
Sum of 3.column=188

Matrix A3 (3x3):
 96 84 13
 63 29 80
 97 98 48

print_sum_rows_cols():
   a[0][0] = 96   a[0][1] = 84   a[0][2] = 13
Sum for row 1 = 193
   a[1][0] = 63   a[1][1] = 29   a[1][2] = 80
Sum for row 2 = 172
   a[2][0] = 97   a[2][1] = 98   a[2][2] = 48
Sum for row 3 = 243

   a[0][0] = 96   a[1][0] = 63   a[2][0] = 97
Sum for col 1 = 256
   a[0][1] = 84   a[1][1] = 29   a[2][1] = 98
Sum for col 2 = 211
   a[0][2] = 13   a[1][2] = 80   a[2][2] = 48
Sum for col 3 = 141

bogus_sum_rows_cols() - (n = 2, m = 2):
   a[0][0] = 96   a[0][1] = 84   a[0][2] = 13
Sum for row 0 = 193
   a[1][0] = 13   a[1][1] = 63   a[1][2] = 29
Sum for row 1 = 105
   a[2][0] = 29   a[2][1] = 80   a[2][2] = 97
Sum for row 2 = 206

   a[0][0] = 96   a[1][0] = 13   a[2][0] = 29
Sum for col 0 = 138
   a[0][1] = 84   a[1][1] = 63   a[2][1] = 80
Sum for col 1 = 227
   a[0][2] = 13   a[1][2] = 29   a[2][2] = 97
Sum for col 2 = 139

sum_row_column()(n = 2, m = 2):

   a[0][0] = 96   a[0][1] = 84   a[0][2] = 13
Sum of 1.row=193
   a[1][0] = 13   a[1][1] = 63   a[1][2] = 29
Sum of 2.row=105
   a[2][0] = 29   a[2][1] = 80   a[2][2] = 97
Sum of 3.row=206

   a[0][0] = 96   a[1][0] = 13   a[2][0] = 29
Sum of 1.column=138
   a[0][1] = 84   a[1][1] = 63   a[2][1] = 80
Sum of 2.column=227
   a[0][2] = 13   a[1][2] = 29   a[2][2] = 97
Sum of 3.column=139

bogus_sum_row_column()(n = 2, m = 2):

   a[0][0] = 96   a[0][1] = 84   a[0][2] = 13
Sum of 1.row=193
   a[1][0] = 13   a[1][1] = 63   a[1][2] = 29
Sum of 2.row=105
   a[2][0] = 29   a[2][1] = 80   a[2][2] = 97
Sum of 3.row=206

   a[0][0] = 96   a[1][0] = 13   a[2][0] = 29
Sum of 1.column=138
   a[0][1] = 84   a[1][1] = 63   a[2][1] = 80
Sum of 2.column=227
   a[0][2] = 13   a[1][2] = 29   a[2][2] = 97
Sum of 3.column=139

Matrix A3 (3x3):
 96 84 13
 63 29 80
 97 98 48

print_sum_rows_cols():
Sum for row 1 = 193
Sum for row 2 = 172
Sum for row 3 = 243

Sum for col 1 = 256
Sum for col 2 = 211
Sum for col 3 = 141

bogus_sum_rows_cols() - (n = 3, m = 3):
Sum for row 0 = 193
Sum for row 1 = 172
Sum for row 2 = 243

Sum for col 0 = 256
Sum for col 1 = 211
Sum for col 2 = 141

sum_row_column()(n = 3, m = 3):

Sum of 1.row=193
Sum of 2.row=172
Sum of 3.row=243

Sum of 1.column=256
Sum of 2.column=211
Sum of 3.column=141

bogus_sum_row_column()(n = 3, m = 3):

Sum of 1.row=193
Sum of 2.row=172
Sum of 3.row=243

Sum of 1.column=256
Sum of 2.column=211
Sum of 3.column=141
```

You can tweak when the debug is set on or off to get different amounts of output, but careful scrutiny of the results shows various discrepancies with the actual sums of rows and columns for the matrices defined in the `main()` program.

The fact that the proposed answer gets the 'right' answer on square matrices when the globals are synchronized with the parameters shows why it is important to do thorough testing.

If the code is only meant to handle square matrices, you'd not have both `n` and `m` (and you wouldn't need both `r` and `c`).  But you shouldn't tie the function to the global variables are all; you should define `r` and `c` (or just one of them if the matrix must be square).

This also shows why an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) is important.  The values in the variables `n` and `m` are not documented in the question or the proposed answer, so it was necessary to tease out the implications of what they represent.

Answer (score -1):

I did in main;

```
case 8:
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                printf("Enter %d.row and %d.column: ",i+1,j+1);
                scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
            }
        }
        sum_row_column(array,n,m,i,j);
        break;
```

and in function;

```
void sum_row_column(int array[n][m],int r,int c,int i,int j)
{
int sumOfColumn=0;
int sumOfRow=0;
printf("\n");
for(i=0;i<r;i++)
{
    sumOfRow=0;
    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    {
        sumOfRow+=array[i][j];
    }
    printf("Sum of %d.row=%d\n",i+1,sumOfRow);
}
printf("\n");
for(j=0;j<r;j++)
{
    sumOfColumn=0;
    for(i=0;i<c;i++)
    {
        sumOfColumn+=array[i][j];   
    }
    printf("Sum of %d.column=%d\n",j+1,sumOfColumn);
}
}
```

and its work! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Passing `i` and `j` as arguments to the function is a travesty. They should be local variables, not arguments.